# Write a table of the first ten squares and cubes

Tags: python

Write a table of the first ten squares and cubes, for example:

```
1 1 1
2 4 8
3 9 27
```

I am very new to python, and I don't know where and how to start.

This is what I did, but I don't know how to put it on a table:

```
def number(start, end):
    return number ** 2, number_2 ** 2
print(number(1,10))
```

Comment: Is that your desired output?

Comment: nah I want to do that for 1-100

Answer (score 2):

You can do something like this if you just need to print the numbers and not to store them.

```
def printTable(start, end):
    for n in range(start, end):
        #print n, n**2, n**3 #this is for python 2.7
        print(n,n**2,n**3) # this is for python 3
```

What you did does not make any sense to me, since you're using variables that do not exist in the scope of the function (`number` and `number_2`), and there's no iteration from `start` to `end`.

Now, if you want you can store them in the following pythonic way:

```
yourCubes = [[x,x**2,x**3] for x in range(start, end)]
```

This will create a list of lists, each one containing the powers of the number (1 to 3 in this case).

Comment: what does "\n" do?

Comment: "\n" is the symbol for a new line. You print `n,n**2,n**3` in one line, then go on a new line.

Comment: this is how the parenthesis have to be    print (n, n**2, n**3, "\n")? for me to print it, because is telling me that I need the parenthesis to print it.

Comment: I'm really sorry I forgot that Python's `print` function always goes on a new line (been working with c++ lately), so "\n" is not necessary

Comment: @kevin You must be using Python 3

Comment: Are you working with Python 2.7 or 3? `print` without the brackets is for python 2.7

Comment: "\n" is white space character use for new line

Comment: If you're on Python 3 then yes. @kevin

Comment: thats because print() is python 3 and this suggested answer is based on python 2.7 it seems - therefore OP should always place python version tag when asking a python related question

Comment: yea am use python 3

Comment: And, if I solved your problem, feel free to mark this as a solution to potentially help other users possibly facing the same problem to find a solution!